# Canceling previous pending request in React (Apollo client with useQuery)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have on search page where we have search box so when typing continue then it is sending multiple requests for each type. I used debounce to handle this so my request is reduced but now I need to cancel the request which is pending and only the latest should be there

I tried a few methods but it is not working for me.

Apollo client Version - `3.3.21`
React version - `17.0.2` 
React-dom version - `17.0.2` 
Node - `16`

The method which I tried

- `Middleware` [cancelRequest.ts](https://github.com/nirus/fullstack-tutorial/blob/master/final/client/src/cancelRequest.ts).
- `Watchquery` with `queryDeduplication: false`

Comment: I have the same issue , did you find a solution ?

Comment: Are you able to track when react is updating your components vs. when the query is being attempted? When working on a similar function I found that the react state was updating before a query that needed to be run after and resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a debounce on the query itself by using a similar technique as described
[here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9583#issuecomment-1087789647).
I used it to cancel page fetches in cases of "over zealous" navigation between pages. Works like a charm.